# "Oracle Apex error: no data found" when opening a form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a very simple Oracle Apex app. I created a button on the home page. I also created a second page using the "Form" template, and the source for this form is a table in the local database.

I set the button to open the form, and I passed the value of the primary key of this form (it's a column called ID) from the home page to the form page, as this screenshot of the button's behavior shows (3 is the page number of the form, P3_ID is the page item in the form associated with the primary column "ID", and 1 is the value that I passed for P3_ID):

[image: Button target behavior]

The table that the form references is empty, i.e. there is no row with ID equal to 1. Meaning I want to pass the value of 1 to this form so that it automatically create a row with ID of 1 after the user fills out the rest of the form. Here is the form page:

[image: Form]

Now the error. When I run the app and press the button, I get this error:

[image: Error message]

The error says it's from the process called "Initialize form Warcraft Particulars". I searched everywhere and I couldn't find a process by that name anywhere in the app. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-rendering process (in a form) will try to execute query and fetch a row whose ID = 1; as it doesn't exist, Apex raises the `no_data_found` error. That's why you got it (the error).

Moreover, you're doing it wrong - don't pass ID you'd want to *create*, fill it in form's process (or use a database trigger which will put a sequence number into the ID column, or use an identity column if your Oracle database supports it (12c onward)).

Furthermore, I'd suggest a slightly different approach: don't create a form that's alone in the Universe. Approach that lets you both view existing data, update (or delete) it and insert new rows is to use a Wizard and choose a **report with a form**. Exact *naming* is different from one Apex version to another; for example, current apex.oracle.com Apex version is 22.2 and it offers "Interactive report", while the 1st Wizard page lets you choose whether you want (or not) to include a form page (you'd say "Yes").

Anyway: once you find the correct option, choose it and wizard will then create an interactive report page you'd use to

- view current data
- it has an edit icon at the beginning of each row which - when pressed - navigates to the form page where you can edit values or delete entire row
- create new row (by pressing the "Create" button)

and a form page which does what I described a moment ago.

Comment: Where is **report with a form** located? I chose Wizard template but I couldn't find anything like that inside.

Comment: Also if I can't have the user fill the ID in the form nor generate it automatically because I want to fetch it from another table and place it as the primary key for the new row that the form should create. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Which Apex version do you use? In lower (e.g. 20.2), click on "Report" and then "Report with Form".

Comment: If you want to re-use an ID from another table, then create a page process which will a) select that ID from that table, b) put it into the ID item on your page

Comment: I'm using version  22.1.4. Did you mean "Interactive Report" and then "Include Form Page"?

Comment: Where would I add this page process? I would right-click on the button and click Create Dynamic Action?

Comment: Yes, that's "Interactive report" with included Form page. Page process: icons on top-left corner represent Rendering, Dynamic actions, **Processes** and Shared Components - you'd create a process right there, on Processes.

Comment: Where exactly in the Processes tab should I create this process? There are five options: After Submit, Validating, Processing, After Processing, and Ajax Callback. And then how do I link this process to the button so that it get executed only when the button gets clicked.

Comment: That would be "Processing" (or "After submit"). Process fires when you submit the page, and page is - by default - submitted when you press the button (as that's its default option). Additionally, if there are several buttons on the page, you can set (in process' options) that it fires when that very button is being pressed, so that it wouldn't fire on *any* button.

Comment: But the button's behavior is set to "Redirect to page in this Application" so it open the form, not to "Submit page". Will it submit page anyway?

Comment: No, it will redirect to another page. If you want to both submit and redirect, then a) set button to submit, and then - in processes - create a **branch** which will redirect to another page.

Comment: Sweet god finally it worked. I placed the Insert Into process in "After Submit" and then placed the branch in "After Processing". Thank you for your patience kind sir 

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you made it work!

Comment: Just one final question, in the Button's behavior section there's an option called "Database Action" that can be set to Insert, Update, or Delete. What is this option for exactly? Does it have anything to do with the Process that runs in After Submit?

Comment: It is related to Automatic Row Processing (that's a default process wizard creates for you), which then tells it (the process) what to do. If you're uncertain of what *something* does, just click on that property and - in the middle section of Page Designer window - navigate to [Page layout - Page search - **Help**] - it'll show you short info about that *something*.